# How to permanently change a vector in a clojure function with a for loop

Tags: for-loop, vector, clojure

I am trying to make make a function that will get a vector that contains letters and transform it into a vector with letter pairs

```
["a" "b" "c"] to ["ab" "bc"]
```

I found that this function does what I need, but it seems that it doesn't change the vector that I entered as a param, instead it makes a new vector for every iteration.

```
(defn test [param] (for [i (range (count param))] (assoc param i 
(clojure.string/join [(get param i) (get param (inc i))]))))
```

Does anyone have an idea how to permanently change the elements of the vector?

Comment: Clojure data structures,vectors, lists, ... are *immutable*. Functions such as `assoc` return a new data structure much like the old one. Under the hood, they (structurally) share most of what's unchanged, so the performance penalty is generally acceptable.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to make a new vector that will contain only the combinations of the letters and to make the function return that value as the result?

Comment: btw. there is no such thing as a "for loop" in clojure, `for` is a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clojure has a host of built-in fns to do this sort of manipulation. For example:

```
(->> ["a" "b" "c" "d"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     (partition 2 1)       ; generates (("a" "b") ("b" "c") ("c" "d"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     (map clojure.string/join)); joins the pairs
;=> ("ab" "bc" "cd")
```

If you really want a vector, change the `map` to `mapv`